# All my validation isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I posted before about part of my validation not working.  I had to redo some code and now all of it isn't working.

```
public partial class frmPersonnel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Checking validation for the text boxes
            bool isValid = true;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((txtFirstName.Text ?? string.Empty).Trim()))
            {
                txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter first name! <br />";
                isValid = false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((txtLastName.Text ?? string.Empty).Trim()))
            {
                txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter last name! <br />";
                isValid = false;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((txtPayRate.Text ?? string.Empty).Trim()))
            {
                txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter pay rate! <br />";
                isValid = false;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((txtStartDate.Text ?? string.Empty).Trim()))
            {
                txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter start date! <br />";
                isValid = false;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((txtEndDate.Text ?? string.Empty).Trim()))
            {
                txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Please enter end date! <br />";
                isValid = false;
            }

            DateTime dt1;
            DateTime dt2;

            dt1 = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
            dt2 = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text);

            if (DateTime.Compare(dt1, dt2) > 0)
            {
                //Checking if the end date is greater than the start date
                txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                lblError.Text += "Start Date must not be greater than End Date! <br />";
            }

            else
                if (isValid)
            {
                //output information if correct validation
                Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
                Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
                Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
                Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
                Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
                Server.Transfer("frmPersonalVerified.aspx");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frmPersonnel.aspx.cs" Inherits="frmPersonnel" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div align="center"> 
    </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="250px" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
        Width="300px">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="First Name:" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Last Name:" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Pay Rate:" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayRate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Start Date:" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="End Date:" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
            PostBackUrl="~/frmPersonnalVerified.aspx" Text="Submit" 
            onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Had you tried using RequiredFieldValidators?

Comment: @mellamokb:  If I leave the text box blank it doesn't turn the box yellow.

Comment: @sq33G:  I'm sorry, but how do I use RequiredFieldValidators?  Thanks

Comment: Are any exceptions occurring?  You are silently discarding them in your `catch` block.

Comment: @errorstacks:  I made note of it in my question about asking it before.  If you read that question I asked about validating a space in the text box.  I got that to work, but now after some code changing around none of it works.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78xxk8k(v=VS.85).aspx about validator controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your validation is just setting text and label backgrounds.  Nothing in that explicitly tells the application that an error has occurred and must be shown to the user.  So when the code reaches the bottom and hits `Server.Transfer("frmPersonalVerified.aspx");`, it will happily travel to the next page.  You need some sort of flag marking whether validation was successful or not before you go to the next page:

```
        //Checking validation for the text boxes
        bool isValid = true;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((txtFirstName.Text ?? string.Empty).Trim()))
        {
            txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            lblError.Text += "Please enter first name! <br />";
            isValid = false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((txtLastName.Text ?? string.Empty).Trim()))
        {
            txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            lblError.Text += "Please enter last name! <br />";
            isValid = false;
        }
        // etc.
```

Then check `isValid` before going to the next page:

```
        if (isValid)
        {
            //output information if correct validation
            Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
            Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
            Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
            Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
            Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
            Server.Transfer("frmPersonalVerified.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: I changed my code above to reflect what you are saying and it isn't working.  Did I do it right?  Thanks

Comment: Get rid of that `else` and you'll have what I'm trying to describe.  Did you see my comment on the question as well?  While debugging you'll want to remove the `try...catch` around your code otherwise you are silently losing any exceptions that occur.  An exception would stop your code from running, so it's important that they propagate forward so you can see what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that perhaps calling `Trim()` on the result of a Null coalesce which could return `string.Empty` might be the problem.

I would call `Trim()` on the string prior to doing the coalesce.

When you say 'not working' can you clarify a bit? I would imagine an exception is thrown, can you let us know which one?

EDIT: Didn't see the bottom section!